# How to find the max time difference in PostgreSQL that a value stayed on the same state?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I am working for a university project and this came up to me:

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want to get the max duration that an actuator was on a state. For example, cool0 Was for 18 minutes.

The result table should look like this:

```
NAME         COOL0   
State        False
Duration     18
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT — we can read mixed-case text more easily.

Comment: Just tag the DBMS you're actually using, not a random array of them. I assume, from the title, that Postgres is the actual one.

Comment: The visible data does not support your contention that `COOL0` was on for 18 minutes.  Unless my eyes are deceiving me, the 4 records for `COOL0` all have the same actuator time.  In fact, the visible records are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  Your data is a bit hard to follow, but I think:

```
select actuator, state, min(actuator_time), max(actuator_time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by actuator order by actuator_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by actuator, state order by actuator_time) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by actuator, (seqnum- seqnum_s)
```

For the maximum per actuator, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (actuator) actuator, state, min(actuator_time), max(actuator_time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by actuator order by actuator_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by actuator, state order by actuator_time) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by actuator, (seqnum- seqnum_s)
order by actuator, max(actuator_time) - min(actuator_time) desc;
```